# vlookup or index match give no result

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, vlookup, google-docs, formulas

i have a problem with a vlookup and also index&match formula.

First i transpose split and substitute a result from an api call which is in JSON, then i get a list i can use vlookup with, but when trying the result is allways #N/A.

=transpose(split(H7;",")) and =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(E18;"[";"");"]";"");" ";"") are the formulas to get a short list of numbers i would like to use a search for a result and this is existing, because when i replace the formula with the result for what i am looking for with a "normal number", then i get the response from a vlookup or index&match!

Would be cool if someone has an idea for this so i can bring it to work.

Comment: I have imported values from an api call and create with the formulas i mentioned before, a list of numbers and ask with vlookup if this number is existing in different tab row, then i would like to get the result next to it which is a text. The request itself is a number but my formula is also showing a number at the end.

Comment: Post a screenshot or a copy of your data

Comment: Here is an example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U3W9qLp8NLFArMtEQwAQUPC2tIeUBFftXXfLY3YTXyE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out as necessary to delete empty rows from other related sheets without content in it to make it happen to work for this kind of sorting data with index and match.